# How to get Related Contact Records using sortby Date picklist using javaScript in visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller

When i Select SortBy Date using JavaScript Onchange Function in picklist option,Get the Contact Records Based on Date wise like (Today,YesterDay,Lastweek) Using JavaScript in visualforce Page. Plz Help me

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is part of a page that displays a table of data, getting the server-side and client-side logic correct and working together can be quite a lot of work.

I have found it simpler to instead do the sorting entirely at the client-side by making use of a JavaScript library such as [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). However, some care is needed to get the [sorting logic right](https://force201.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/client-side-sorting-and-pagination-of-an-apexpageblocktable-more-on-sorting/).